# Solution to inhomogeneous second order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve this differential equation using Mathematica:

```
1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
  em*V1[x] + (2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep) == 0
```

The general solution of the nonhomogeneous equation can be found as follows:

```
SolGeneralNonHomo = 
 DSolve[1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
    em*V1[x] + (2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep) == 0, 
  V1[x], x]
```

The solution is quite long and I won't report it here. **What matters is that it contains two definite integrals**, $\int_1^x ... dK[1]$ and $\int_1^x ... dK[2]$.

The solution should be equal to the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

The general solution of the homogeneous equation can be found as follows:

```
SolGeneralHomo = 
 DSolve[1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
    em*V1[x] == 0, V1[x], x]
```

A particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation can be found using the Variation of Parameters Formula. More precisely, given the nonhomogeneous equation:

$$a(x) y′′(x) + b(x) y′(x) + c(x) y(x) = f(x)$$

a particular solution is given by:

$$y1(x) \left( \int \frac{y2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} dx \right) + y2(x) \left( \int \frac{y1(x) f(x)}{a(x) W(x)} dx \right)$$

where $W(x)$ is the Wronskian:

$$W(x) = y1(x) y2′(x) - y1′(x) y2(x)$$

Therefore, I do exactly this in Mathematica:

```
a[x_] := 1/2*\[Sigma]X^2;
y1[x_] := 
  HermiteH[-(em/a1), (Sqrt[a1] x)/\[Sigma]X - (a0 \[Delta])/(
    a1^(3/2) \[Sigma]X)];
y2[x_] := 
  Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/
   2, ((Sqrt[a1] x)/\[Sigma]X - (a0 \[Delta])/(a1^(3/2) \[Sigma]X))^2];
f[x_] := (2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep);
W[x_] := y1[x]*D[y2[x], x] - D[y1[x], x]*y2[x];
SolParticularNonHomo = 
 y1[x]*(\[Integral](y2[x]*(-f[x]))/(a[x]*W[x]) \[DifferentialD]x) + 
  y2[x]*(\[Integral](y1[x]*f[x])/(a[x]*W[x]) \[DifferentialD]x)
```

**The solution derived in this alternative way contains two indefinite integrals**, $\int ... dx$. Can anyone explain this discrepancy? That is the only difference between the two solutions.

What confuses me is that **the solution with the indefinite integrals does not satisfy the differential equation**. Why? Indeed:

```
tester = (V1[x] /. SolGeneralHomo[[1]]) + SolParticularNonHomo;
SolvedGeneralNonHomo = 
  1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*D[tester, {x, 2}] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*
     D[tester, x] - em*(tester) + (
    2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep) // FullSimplify;
SolvedGeneralNonHomo == 0
```

does not return `True` but rather:

```
(4 (x - ep (a0 + a1 x) \[Lambda]))/(em - ep) == 0
```

This is equal to $f(x)+f(x)$ rather than $f(x)-f(x)$ but I can't spot any wrong signs. Any advice?

Comment: $\int f(x) \; dx = \int_1^x f(K) \; dK + C$

Comment: How is C determined?

Comment: $C$ is an indefinite constant. It's standard calculus (at least in every US textbook): Every indefinite integral is determined up to an arbitrary constant. There are a `C[1]` and a `C[2]` in the `DSolve` solution that accounts for the indefinite integrals.

Comment: I apologise. Let me ask the appropriate question: given my solution that has an indefinite integral, how do I know that I need to write a definite integral with those specific limits of integration? Where do those limits come from?

Comment: The starting value $1$ in the integral is arbitrary and Mathematica automatically uses $1$ if no initial condition is given. Add the condition `V1[0] == v0`, and Mathematica will choose $0$ for the lower limit. The lower limit should depend on where the coefficients of the ODE are continuous, but I do not know/recall whether Mathematica checks this. Note that $\int f(x) \; dx = \int_a^x f(K) \; dK + C$ for any $a$, provided $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood containing $a$ and $x$. It appears that Mma applies variation of parameters with definite integrals instead of indefinite ones.

Comment: If I read it right -- difficult to do when the code is not in InputForm -- it seems the residual is equal to $f + f$ instead of $f - f$. That suggests a sign error somewhere. But I don't have time to track it down right now. So take it as a hint, which may or may not be on target.

Comment: You are right, it's f + f instead of f - f. But I really can't find a sign error. I have tired to write everything from scratch, and still nothing. Any advice what I could look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Math comment:*

Most textbooks present variation of parameters in the form shown in the OP:

$$y_1(x) \left( \int \frac{y_2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx \right) + y_2(x) \left( \int \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx \right) \,.$$

The integrals are presented as indefinite, but in textbooks (at least the few I've used), the $+C$ that usually accompanies an indefinite integral is omitted: We're looking for *any* particular solution, and we can ignore the constant of integration (set it to zero) and use any antiderivative we happen to find for each integral.

Since, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$\int_a^x g(t)\;dt$$
is a particular antiderivative of (a continuous) $g(x)$,
$$\int_1^x \frac{y_2(K) (-f(K))}{a(K) W(K)} dK$$
can serve as a particular antiderivative of
$$\int \frac{y_2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} dx \,.$$
The same is true for
$$\int_a^x \frac{y_2(K) (-f(K))}{a(K) W(K)} dK$$
for any initial point $a$ (as long as the coefficients of the differential equation are continuous in a neighborhood of $a$).

---

Now, if we were to keep the $+C$ in the variation of parameters, instead of getting a particular solution to the inhomogenous ODE,
we would get the general solution:

$$\eqalign{
y_1(x) & \left( \int \frac{y_2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx \right) + y_2(x) \left( \int \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx\right) \cr
&=
y_1(x) \left( \int \frac{y_2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx {+} C_1 \right) + y_2(x) \left( \int \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx {+} C_2 \right) \cr
&=
C_1 y_1(x)+ C_2y_2(x) \; + \cr
&\qquad y_1(x) \left( \int \frac{y_2(x) (-f(x))}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx \right) + y_2(x) \left( \int \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{a(x) W(x)} \; dx \right)\,. \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. There is just one thing I still don't understand. From your notation it seems that the very last line is the general solution of the inhomogeneous equation: it is the sum of the general solution to the homogeneous equation (c1 y1 + c2 y2) and a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation (y1 int ... dx + y2 int ... dx). But substituting it into the DE does not satisfy it. Indeed I obtain that f(x) = 0. What am I not understanding correctly? Why is it not right to use the indefinite integral?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details to clarify this issue.

Comment: Sorry it does not return f(x)=0, but something similar